# How to translate assembly instructions using Java Parser?

Tags: java, security, parsing, malware, malware-detection

I am doing work on the feature extraction of malware .I want to translate the assembly instructions, by discarding the operands and encoding each operator with a unique number (say instruction ID).

I want output like this:
Instruction sequence: MOV→CALL→ SUB→MOV
IDS of Instruction: 240→33→386→240

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Map<>`,

Comment: You can use a Map to lookup the number and return the text

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public static Map<Integer, String> LOOK_UP = new HashMap<>();
static {
    LOOK_UP.put(240, "MOV");
    ...
}

public static String InstructionToString(Integer i) {
    if(LOOK_UP.contains(i)) {
        return LOOK_UP.get(i);
    } else {
        //return error of some kinde
    }
}

public static List<String> InstructionsToString(Integer[] arrayOfInst) {
    List<String> ret = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i : arrayOfInst) {
        ret.add(InstructionToString(i));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

(I've not check the syntax of the code)